# What is the maximum amount I can send with "sendmany()"

Tags: sending, sendtoaddress

If I use the `sendmany();` function is there a maximum of the output amount? 
Example:

```
The maximum would be 0.01 BTC

data={'address1':amount1,'address2':amount2};

amount1+amount2 = 0.02 BTC

-> But then it would be above the maximum.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can send more than the Bitcoin contained within a single output, or whether the combined Bitcoin can exceed the Bitcoin in your wallet?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum output amount is the full wallet balance minus any transaction fees, many inputs up to and including all that have a positive balance can be combined to create the utxo set used in the transaction.